# Visual basic list files

Tags: vb.net, listbox, hide

I have the following code to display files from a directory, which works perfectly;

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
ListBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles("C:\users\matt\pics\")
End Sub
```

But, is there any way to hide the "C:\users\matt\pics\" And only show the filenames?

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the System.IO.Path namespace. You will want to invoke GetFileName on each item in the string array returned by GetFiles before binding the array to the listbox. The easiest way to do this would be to use linq, although you could take an iterative looping approach too.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ's `Select` method to strip off the directory name and just display the filename.  The `ToList` call converts the result from `Select` to something that implements `IList` or `IListSource` so the result can be used as a data source (`ToArray` would work as well).

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles("C:\users\matt\pics\").Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I've been struggling with this forever!